# Trocar/Editar palavra já traduzida no WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tradução

Eu estou configurando uma loja virtual WooCommerce (WordPress) e instalei recentemente uma tradução `pt_BR`. Está tudo traduzido corretamente, menos o termo:

> QUICK VIEW

que aparece traduzido como - `VISUALIZA RÁPIDA` e o correto seria - `VISUALIZAÇÃO RÁPIDA`, ou apenas: `VISUALIZAR`.

Como faço para editar a tradução dessa palavra, ou até mesmo trocar a palavra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de gerir traduções, tanto para editar ou criar novas traduções, é utilizando o plugin [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/).

O plugin **Loco Translate** permite-te editar arquivos `PO` e `POT` através do teu navegador. Estes arquivos são os ficheiros usados para a localização de traduções de plugins e temas WordPress.

> #### O que é a localização?
>
> A Localização descreve o processo subsequente de traduzir um tema
>   internacionalizado. A Localização é abreviada como `l10n` (porque
>   existem 10 letras entre o `l` e o `n`.) [#](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/#what-is-localization)

#### Sobre os arquivos POT (Portable Object Template)

Este arquivo contém as `strings` originais (em Inglês) no teu tema. Aqui está um exemplo de entrada do arquivo `POT`:

```
#: theme-name.php:123
msgid "Page Title"
msgstr ""
```

A primeira linha é um comentário que normalmente é o número da sequência do arquivo e linha. A linha `msgid` é a string original e `msgstr` é a secção onde a tradução entra.

No entanto para traduzirmos um texto através do `.POT` não é tão simples como no plugin que mencionei acima, não basta apenas traduzir o ficheiro `.POT` do tema, atualizar e enviar o ficheiro:

```
#: theme-name.php:123
msgid "Page Title"
msgstr "Título da Página"
```

Existe um processo a ser feito como é explicado [aqui nesta documentação](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/#translate-po-file) do WordPress.

> Para saber mais sobre isto, visita as respectivas páginas de documentação:
>
> [Translate WordPress - Gettext](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/gettext/)
>   [WordPress function - Localization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Utilizei o plugin Loco Translate que é bem intuitivo e eficaz.