# Traduzir strings do Wordpress de português para inglês

Tags: wordpress, tradução

Estou com uma instalação do Wordpress em pt-br e tenho procurado inúmeras formas de tradução de tema, strings mas nenhuma tem dado certo. A maioria pega um tema que o padrão é inglês e eu traduzo para o português.

Eu precisava "traduzir" algumas strings customizadas do menu de português para inglês, cheguei a usar o wpml porém bagunçou totalmente meu tema. Alguém tem alguma idéia mais simples de como traduzir na mão?

Comment: Já tentou editar diretamente os arquivos?

Comment: @AmandaLima, tentei com o poedit (não sei se é isso o diretamente), mas ele não encontra as minhas strings customizadas

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94444/11886). Se o tema estiver preparado para "Localização", esta solução vai te ajudar. Senão, a única solução é como a @AmandaLima disse, alterar as strings nos próprios arquivos.

Comment: @haykou, se são poucas strings que você precisa traduzir, abra o arquivo do Wordpress com um editor de texto qualquer (Notepad++ no caso do Windows, Gedit no caso do Linux), procure a string e substitua pela palavra traduzida.

Comment: O ideal seria mostrar um exemplo de como é esse tema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução padrão no WordPress para traduções é a [Internacionalização](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). Você prepara o seu tema/plugin para que ele possa receber diferentes traduções. Basicamente, você abraça suas `strings` de texto em métodos que o próprio WP fornece. Da documentação

```
$hello =  __( 'Hello, dear user!', 'my-text-domain' );
```

O método `__()`, além de atribuir o valor *Hello, dear user!* para a variável, também o adiciona ao domínio *my-text-domain*. Se você precisa fazer `echo` dentro do seu código, você usa o método [`_e()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e), da seguinte forma:

```
_e( 'Using this option you will make a fortune!', 'my-text-domain' );
```

Depois de ter todo o seu código preparado, com as `strings` dentro de um domínio, você precisa gerar um arquivo `.pot` que vai conter todas as `strings` internacionalizadas do seu código. Quando preciso fazer isso, uso o [EasyPO](http://www.eazypo.ca/).

Em posse do arquivo `.pot`, você pode usar o [Poedit](http://poedit.net/) para traduzir todas as `strings` e gerar um novo domínio. Depois é só setar o `locale` e tudo deve funcionar. Esse processo torna **MUITO** mais fácil a manutenção das traduções.

[Aqui](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/internationalizing-localizing-wordpress-theme/) e [aqui](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014) você pode ler (em inglês) dois artigos excelentes sobre como internacionalizar o seu tema/plugin. Também tem uma discussão interessante sobre isso [aqui](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149212/how-to-create-pot-files-with-poedit)

Comment: acabei precisando traduzir outra parte e utilizei o qtranslator X com o _e() e foi bem melhor do que o if que eu fiz, que serviu apenas em um caso único

Answer (score 3):

Não achei uma solução mais prática, troquei as strings manualmente mesmo, conforme o ?lang do Wordpress, segue a minha solução:

```
 <?php 
              $mylocale = get_bloginfo('language'); //Pega o lang padrão do tema
              if($mylocale == 'pt-BR') { ?>
             <p>Palavra em português</p>
<?php }
             elseif($mylocale == 'en-US'){ ?>

             <p>Palavra em inglês</p>

<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Boa dica! +1! :) Só reorganizaria o código de maneira diferente para evitar o abrimento e fechamento da tag `<?php ?>` várias vezes para fazer *output* do código HTML, o que é desnecessário pois podes fazê-lo [desta maneira](http://jsfiddle.net/rhv3vg49/).