# Utilizando multi linguagem em Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um site em *Wordpress*, e preciso que alguns conteúdos no site (menus, fotos e etc) estejam em 3 línguas diferentes.

Como é possível fazer isso sem precisar criar um novo *Wordpress* para cada língua?

Comment: Você está procurando por internacionalização. Dei uma resposta detalhada sobre isso [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95562/23051)

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Não quero só traduzir, para isso eu editaria o .po do template. Quero ter páginas diferentes para línguas diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconheço qualquer função nativa do *wordpress* que trabalhe com multi-linguagem, e quando preciso utilizo duas maneiras, dependendo do que o trabalho pede.

Recomendo que utilize o plugin [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) para conteúdos gerenciáveis ele ira facilitar tua vida, alem de ser bem documentado a abrangência dele também é boa mesmo em versão gratuita. Para o **método I** utilizarei ele como referência, porém caso não queria utilizar você pode usar as funções nativa do *wordpress*, para criação de campos chegando ao mesmo resultado.

---

Para capturar a língua atual, selecionada pelo usuário utilizo o seguinte código em ambos os métodos:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
        if ($lang == 'en'):
            $flag_1 = 'es';
            $flag_2 = 'pt-br';
        elseif ($lang == 'es'):
            $flag_1 = 'pt-br';
            $flag_2 = 'en';
        else:
            $flag_1 = 'en';
            $flag_2 = 'es';
        endif;
    ?>
    <li>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input name="lang" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $flag_1; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
            <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
            <input type="submit" role="button" value="<?php echo $flag_1; ?>">
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input name="lang" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $flag_2; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
            <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
            <input type="submit" role="button" value="<?php echo $flag_2; ?>">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sim, utilizo dois `<form>`! Nesse exemplo, há 3 línguas: Português, Inglês e Espanhol, onde apos capturar a língua selecionada cada um dos `<form>` recebe uma das línguas não selecionada, podendo ser trocada futuramente.

Dentro do functions.php insiro o seguinte código:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie('lang', 'pt-br', (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600)), '/');
    wp_redirect(site_url());
    die;
}
if (isset($_POST['lang'])) {
    setcookie('lang', $_POST['lang'], (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600)), '/');
    /*Rede
    wp_redirect(site_url($_POST['redirect']));*/
    //local
    wp_redirect(site_url());
    die;
```

}

Nada demais, apenas atribuo o valor vindo do *post* para um *Cookie*.

---

**Método I:**

Nessa forma duplica-se os campos de conteúdos dentro de uma mesma pagina utilizando sempre a mesma URL.

Por exemplo, utilizando o ACF crio dentro da pagina "exemplo" três campos, "conteudo_br", "conteudo_es" e "conteudo_en", os quais se referem ao mesmo campo, porém cada um é responsável pelo conteúdo em cada linguagem.

No código faço a seguinte verificação:

```
<?php
    if ( $_COOKIE['lang'] == "en"):
        $conteudo = get_field('conteudo_en');
    elseif ($_COOKIE['lang'] == "es"):
        $conteudo = get_field('conteudo_es');
    else:
        $conteudo = get_field('conteudo_br');
    endif;
?>
<article>
    <h2>Título do conteúdo</h2>
    <?php echo $conteudo; ?>
</article>
```

Através do if atribuo a variável *$conteúdo* o campo da língua atual, verificando o *Cookie*.

Vantagem desse método:
Crio apenas um menu, pois a pagina lincada sera sempre a mesma.

Desvantagem:
Para SEO, a página sempre terá o mesmo nome, por exemplo a página de contato, será sempre "www.meudominio.com/contato" e não terá um "/contact" por exemplo para a língua inglesa.

**Método II:**

Você pode duplicar as paginas, onde  você não precisaria criar "conteudo_br", "conteudo_es" e "conteudo_en", basta apenas criar um campo, por exemplo "conteudo" e atribuir o mesmo as três paginas (inglês, espanhol e português), onde cada uma fica com o respectivo conteúdo da linguagem.

No código você apenas teria que verificar a linguagem atual do *cookie* e trocar o link dos menus ao invés do conteúdo em si como o **método I** sugere.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
    if ($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'en'):
        $item_1 = 'contact';
    elseif ($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'es'):
        $item_1 = 'contacto';
    else:
        $item_1 = 'contato';
    endif;
?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); echo '/'.$item_1; ?>"><?php echo $item_1; ?></a>
```

Acima o código seleciona o *href* atribuindo ao *$item_1* dependendo do *Cookie*.

Vantagem desse método:
O conteúdo fica mais fácil de ser gerenciável pois a quantidade de campos por paginas é menor.

Em relação ao SEO, cada pagina terá sua devida URL em cada linguagem.

Desvantagem:
Em sites que possuem muitas paginas, esse modelo pode gerar um acumulo excessivo de páginas, pois para cada página serão criadas 3, uma para cada língua.

---

Enfim, analise o que seu trabalho necessita e utilize a forma que melhor te se adeque.

Também se preferir você pode utilizar algum plugin que faça todo esse trabalho por você, podendo conferir alguns [na página de plugins do wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/multilanguage).

Se mesmo apos o passo a passo você estiver com dificuldades, sugiro que você replique o conteúdo para três subdomínios como es.site.com, en.site.com e site.com ... Por mais que eu não recomende esse método, devido a duplicidade de conteúdo, ele também é valido.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu faria para que um menu exista somente em uma linguagem e nas outras ele não exista? Seria um `display: none` ou alguma coisa do tipo? O primeiro código eu não entendi muito bem, onde você colocaria ele? No index?

Comment: Você citou que existe plugin's que fazem esse processo, mas saberia dizer se há algum que segue essa sua mesma logica?

Comment: @GiovanniBernini, em relação a linguagem você pode simplesmente inserir o código HTML entre os "if" do php, e então ele sera mostrando apenas naquela determinada lingua, pois com display none seria um tanto gambiarra. Em relação ao primeiro código vai do bom senso, eu geralmente coloco dentro da header ou do nav como é algo que o usuário pode mudar a qualquer momento.

Comment: Plugins são um tanto limitados, por isso escrevi esse texto gigante para que você possa fazer no "braço" já que é algo bem especifico e não conheço nenhum plugin que faça isso de maneira satisfatória.

Comment: Entendi, mas vou ter que bater um pouco a cabeça para fazer, pois eu uso WP faz pouco tempo, resolvi migrar do Joomla! no projeto errado, rsrsrs. Fico com duvida nessa parte de chamar as páginas. A página `conteudo`, que carregará o código para chamar as páginas com a linguagem correta? Mas o que seria um "campo" é uma outra página? Eu criaria uma página "contatoconteudo" e mais 3 páginas por língua, e na página "contatoconteudo" estará o código do seu ultimo exemplo? Essa página "contatoconteudo" seria uma redirecionadora?

Comment: Fazer 3 Wordpress diferentes em subdominios, não seria uma solução boa né? (site.com, es.site.com, br.site.com). Queria ter essa diferença entre as línguas, na url. Mas acredito que um "site.com/pt-br/" seria mais fácil.

Comment: Um campo seria um campo, por exemplo o editor de texto é um campo, o titulo é um campo os quais você consegue acessar via the_algumacoisa(), com o ACF você consegue criar campos personalizados mais facilmente que a forma nativa de wordpress, de uma lida minima sobre e você era entender é bem facil!

Comment: Talvez seja @giovanniBernini, se você estiver com dificuldade para entender o passo a passo a melhor maneira seria mesmo fazer um subdominio para cada linguagem, porem eu já tive problemas de redirecionamento por causa de subdominios, mas você pode tentar, também é uma alternativa valida!

Comment: Acho que eu acabei me entendendo aqui, esse trecho de código que você deu como exemplo no método 2, ele teria de existir nas 3 páginas? Onde eu estou me complicando é nisso, onde que esse ultimo código ficaria? Eu atualmente já tenho as páginas para cada língua montada, então acredito que esse método 2 séria melhor e mais fácil. Não sei se consegui explicar a minha duvida dessa vez mais claramente, mas agradeço pela ajuda!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31374/discussion-between-rafael-kendrik-and-giovanni-bernini).

Answer (score 1):

Tenta esse plugin, ele tem vários idiomas
https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/

Comment: Mas será que com esse eu consigo editar algumas coisas como os exemplos que eu citei? Ou será só para traduzir os posts.